# How to calculate statistical "difference" of two samples in 0-100 range?

Tags: statistics

There are two groups of people, target and neutral

There are two group of events X and others

We're making assumption that people from target group react on event X very different to others.

We have some sets of reaction numeric values on different type of events by those two groups. And after running Student's `T-Test` in excel I get `0.032` for target group and `0.55` for others so I can tell that target group react on X different but is it possible to measure how much different in `0-100` range?

example of data set (not real data set) for both groups looks like

```
30, 20, 45, 15, 26 ... - reaction on X event
10, 14, 22, 8, 13 ... - reactions on other events
```

What can I use to measure how much reaction `X` different (alike in T-Test) to reaction on other events in `0-100` range and is it possible in general?

Comment: You could probably look at the sample means and conclude that the difference is statistically significant based on t-test with, i.e., 5% significance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data are approximately normal then use a [Welch 2-sample t test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test). This test does not assume
that the two groups are sampled from populations with equal *variances.*

When you mention the `0-100` range, perhaps you mean the P-value which
gives the probability of a more extreme difference between groups than
observed in your data, if the two groups are really equal (null hypothesis).
A common standard is to reject the null hypothesis that the groups are
equal if the P-value is less than 5%. Most statistical software computes
the P-value of the test. Here is one description of the [Welch test in Excel](http://www.real-statistics.com/students-t-distribution/two-sample-t-test-uequal-variances/).

Comment: That will work, thank you